# SQL Count() child Rows based on values from Parent

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I have a Parent Table

```
EventKey   Event Name
1001       Event 1
1002       Event 2
1003       Event 3
```

This is my child Table

```
EventKey   EventAssignee
1001       Assignee 11
1001       Assignee 12
1002       Assignee 21
1002       Assignee 22
```

The below is my SQL Query

```
select p.EventKey As Event_Key,
       p.Event_Name As EventName,
       (select count(*) 
        from Child c 
        where c.eventkey = p.eventkey) As Assignee_Count
from ParentTable p
```

This is giving me a SQL Error unexpected token Child. Please let me know where am going wrong

Am Expecting the output to be

```
Event_Key Event_Name Assignee_Count
1001      Event 1    2    
1002      Event 2    2
1003      Event 3    0
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with mysql ***and*** DB2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try as this:

```
select p.EventKey As EventKey , p.EventName As EventName, count(c.assignee) As Assignee_Count
from Parent p left join child c on p.EventKey=c.EventKey 
group by p.EventKey,p.EventName
```

Comment: Hi @gayathri Thanks it works but I need the other unmatched values from parent table . In that case the parent row should display the count as 0 as there are no matching in child table. I have edited the table accodringly

Comment: select p.EventKey As EventKey , p.EventName As EventName,count(c.assignee) As Assignee_Count 
from Parent p left join child c on p.EventKey=c.EventKey
group by p.EventKey,p.EventName

Answer (score 1):

Try to group by Event_Key in your subquery

```
select count(*) 
  from Child c 
  where c.eventkey = p.eventkey 
  group by p.eventkey
```

Comment: It might help to show the entire query, but I suggest a CTE rather than a subquery.